# How to make widget text flexible dynamically on resize widget

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, text, widget

I'm working on widgets using gridstack. I want to make widgets same as shown in the image. The problem I'm facing is when I resize the widget the text is not flexible.

I want the text to change it size with the widget size. I'm stuck on it from few days and don't know what to do. I did media queries but it didn't working.

More over I'm using angularjs and bootstrap.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmviU.png]

**Here's the code which make the grid dynamically:**

```
<div class="container-fixed-lg" style="margin-left:10px; margin-top:75px">

<div gridstack class="grid-stack grid1" id="12345" options="options">
   <div gridstack-item ng-repeat="value in currentTab.widgets" id="{{value.widgetId}}" class="grid-stack-item" gs-item-x="value.xAxis" gs-item-y="value.yAxis" gs-item-width="value.width" gs-item-height="value.height">
      <div class="grid-stack-item-content ui-draggable-handle panel panel-default" id="{{value.widgetId}}" style="height:tempHeight; margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;">
         <div dynamic="value.widgetDirective"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have use different css methods to handle and jquery method to get the width and height but i think im lacking somewhere. Im new to javascript and developing.

Comment: Here on stackoverflow you should provide code which can be discussed. Otherwise your question could be too broad and wont meet the "off-topic"-regulations...

Comment: Ok got  it this is what im doing :

Comment: I have added code but its not showing here? how to do that ?